# Update data stored in ElasticSearch in Java with TransportClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to update data in Elastic Search in my Java program with *TranportClient* class. I know I can UPDATE in this way :

```
   XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
       .field("source.ivarId", source.ivarId)
       .field("source.channel", source.channel)
       .field("source.bacId", source.bacId).endObject();
   UpdateResponse response = client.prepareUpdate(_index, _type, _id).setDoc(builder.string()).get();
```

while *source* is my user-defined class which contains 3 fields : *ivarId*, *channel* and *bacId*.

But I want to know is there any method that could do the same thing, but using another more *efficient* and *easier* way, so that I don't need to assign ***each field*** inside a class? For example, can I do like this?

```
   XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
       .field("source", source).endObject();
   UpdateResponse response = client.prepareUpdate(_index, _type, _id).setDoc(builder.string()).get();
```

I tried the latter method, and I got this exception :

```
MapperParsingException[object mapping for [source] tried to parse field [source] as object, but found a concrete value]
```

I'm using **Java 1.8.0.121**, and both versions of **ElasticSearch** and **TransportClient** are **5.1**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is much more easier than I thought.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String sourceJsonString = gson.toJson(updateContent);
UpdateResponse response = client
    .prepareUpdate(_index, "logs", id).setDoc(sourceJsonString).get();
```

*updateContent* is the object that contained new data, just to transform it to Json string, then use that to update, done.